# The method that has enabled=false not getting printed using IClassListener in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The Testcase code looks like below.

```
public class LaunchBrowser{
    
    @Test(enabled=false)
        public void browser() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("Test 1");
    }
}
```

The CustomListener class looks like below:

```
public class ListenerImplements extends TestBase implements IClassListener {
    
    @Override
    public void onBeforeClass(ITestClass testClass) {
        ITestNGMethod[] methods = testClass.getTestMethods();

        for (ITestNGMethod method: methods) {
            System.out.println(method.getEnabled());
        }
    }
```

I am calling the Listener Class inside the testNg.xml file.

When I use the above code nothing gets printed. But when I use multiple test methods in a class with one being enabled and another one being disabled, I can see the console with disabled testcase as well.

The problem is when we have only one test method and that method is disabled using testng function `enabled=false`.

**My requirement is to know whether the testcase is enabled/disabled**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the test class is omitted when all test method is disabled.
What you can do is implement `ISuiteListener` instead, where
[getAllMethods()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.testng/testng/7.6.1/org/testng/ISuite.html#getAllMethods()) are enabled methods
and [getExcludedMethods()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.testng/testng/7.6.1/org/testng/ISuite.html#getExcludedMethods()) are disabled methods.

```java
public class SuiteListener implements ISuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        suite.getAllMethods().forEach(
                m ->
                        System.out.println("%s %s %s".formatted(m.getTestClass(), m.getMethodName(), "enabled")));
        suite.getExcludedMethods().forEach(
                m ->
                        System.out.println("%s %s %s".formatted(m.getTestClass(), m.getMethodName(), "disabled")));
    }
}
```